# Ajax request fails in Microsoft Edge Browser for loopback ipaddress (127.0.0.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, microsoft-edge

I have a HTTP server running locally on my machine. I need to make an XHR call to a url i.e. (https://127.0.0.1:8989/test).
When i hit the same url in browser, it works fine. but the XHR request fails with following error.

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

Below is the code snippet.

```
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        url: "https://127.0.0.1:8989/test",
        type: "POST",
        data: null
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function(textStatus) {
        console.log("fails");
    });
}
```

All other browsers, it's working fine except Microsoft Edge Browser.
Appreciate for any guidance on this.

Comment: The port number is different in the ajax request. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Probably some security issues in IE.